# Oracle SQL output wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not being able to produce the desired results of this question:

Display alphabetically the full name, job, salary, department number for each employee who earns less than the best paid unionized employee

- unionized employees are not managers presidents of vice presidents
  And do not work in SALES or MARKETING departments
- Full name should be displayed as Firstname  Lastname and should have the heading Employee.
- Salary should be left-padded with the = symbol till the width of 12 characters. It should have an alias Salary.
- salary is formatted as a currency amount incl. thousand separator, but no decimals
- Limit the width of the Employees name to 25 characters.

The output lines should look like this sample line:

```
Jonathon Taylor     SA_REP  ==== $8,600     80
```

My query so far:

```
select last_name || ', ' || first_name "full name", job_id, salary, department_id
from employees   
where salary < ANY
          (SELECT MAX(salary)
          from employees e join departments d
          where e.job_id <> 'AC_MGR' OR 'AD_VP' OR 'AD_PRES'
          AND d.department_name <> 'SALES' OR 'MARKETING'
          GROUP BY department_id)
```

If someone can help me out and point me in the right direction of how to get the proper output, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you grouping in the max subquery?

Comment: Parens around the `OR`s. Actually that expression isn't even valid: you want `e.job not in ('AC_MGR', 'AD_VP', 'AD_PRES')`. Same with `department_name`. And agreed that you don't need the `GROUP BY` either. And once your subquery returns a single row the `ANY` will no longer be necessary.

Comment: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 15

Comment: i get that error correcting what you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT substr(first_name || ' ' || last_name, 1, 25) as NAME
      , job_id 
      , lpad( to_char(salary, '$999,999.99' ), 12, '=') as SALARY
FROM employees
WHERE salary <
(
    SELECT MAX(salary)
    FROM employees e INNER JOIN departments d
        ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    WHERE e.job_id NOT IN ('AC_MGR', 'AD_VP', 'AD_PRES') AND
          d.department_name NOT IN ('SALES', 'MARKETING')
)
```

Some problems from your original query which I fixed:

- Fixed the concatenation in `SELECT` to match your desired output
- Added a `JOIN` condition, since your original query is doing a `CROSS JOIN` (which you probably don't want)
- Replaced the `OR` conditions in the `WHERE` with `WHERE ... NOT IN`
- Removed `GROUP BY` from the subquery, since it didn't serve any purpose

Comment: how would you insert the thousandths seperator ? i.e $8,777. also limit the name to 25 chars. Thanks

Comment: @13design What do you mean by limit the "name" to 25 characters?  You do realize that the full name is a concatenation of the first and last name columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - the OP is referring to the formatting requirements included in the question. Ironically those requirements were obfuscated by  poor formatting choices in the question text, Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is HR schema, right brother? You need `inner join` **Employees** and **Departments** with both `department_id` are matched. You can use `WITH` syntax for your query:

```
with temp as (
select last_name || ', ' || first_name as "Full name",
job_id, salary as slr, d.department_id
from employees e inner join departments d on e.department_id=d.department_id
where e.job_id NOT in ('AC_MGR','AD_VP','AD_PRES')
and d.department_name NOT in ('SALES', 'MARKETING')
)
select * from temp where slr <= (select max(slr) from temp);
```